# Convert ConsoleWriteLine to textbox

Tags: c#, html, regex

I am facing issues in Console WriteLine to textbox.
My codes for this

```
 Console.WriteLine(string.Format("IP: {0} Port: {1}", ip2, port));
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 sb.AppendLine(string.Format("IP: {0} Port: {1}", ip2, port));
 textBox2.Text = sb.ToString();
```

While Messagebox works,

```
 MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(ip2+":"+port));
```

Here is my full [source codes](https://iandotnet.wordpress.com/tag/parse-hidemyass-com/).
What am i doing wrong here?

UPDATED:

Another [solution](http://saezndaree.wordpress.com/2009/03/29/how-to-redirect-the-consoles-output-to-a-textbox-in-c/) by using textwriter redirect console output to textbox.

Comment: How can you have a console app AND text box (Windows/Web Forms?) in the same bit of code?

Comment: @Andrew, every application (independent from its UI) can write to console. While it might not be visible for the normal user, just when debugging in the output window or when running from cmd.exe

Comment: Well you learn something new every day then :)

Comment: @Andrew my C# project is created with windows forms, the codes I saw in the site created with Console application.

Comment: What exactly the issue? Is textbox not showing full string? Use multi-line text box for that.

Comment: Multi-line textbox does not show also

Comment: Does encoding UTF-8 will affect the result ?

Comment: sb.ToString() has data what you want in it? try to debug that code line. Look at RononDe's answer below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a multi-line texbox? `AppendLine(`) adds the new line characters at the end of your string, which causes single-lined textboxes to display the new line instead of the line with the text.

Try using `Append()` instead:

```
sb.Append(string.Format("IP: {0} Port: {1}", ip2, port));
```